# get ViewPage html element values from _Layout Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following view page

```
@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="sample"></div>
```

_Layout Page

```
<div class="button" type="button"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button").click(function () {
            alert($("#sample").val());
         });
     }
</script>
```

How can I get sample value when click  button in _LayoutPage, above alert not showing the value

Comment: A `<div>` does not have a value - `alert($("#sample").text());` assuming you have some text between the tags (or `$("#sample").html()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke is that possible to take values inside `<td>` instead DIVs

Comment: If you have `<td id="sample">some text</td>` the the above would alert "some text"

Comment: @kez `<td>` also not have `value` attribute, you can call `text()` to get inner html

Comment: @StephenMuecke if I have hidden elements in view page how to extract those  , if I want get Id of this `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)`

Comment: @kez `$("#ID").val()` - `@Html.HiddenFor()` will create `<input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" />`

Comment: The you need to `.find()` it - `$('#sample').find('#ID').val()`, but since `id` attributes should be unique, then `$("#ID").val()` will work

Comment: if  this `model.ID` outside any id , can I use as `$("#ID").val()` , its currently undefined :(

Comment: @StephenMuecke and Thanks All thats working, learned lot :)